How do I make terrain for a game, best approach for texturizing it
I use Godot, I'm too stupid for C++, don't like blueprints and Unity, well news from last year... so Godot it is. I decided to make a Zelda Classic clone, something simple as exercise and in 2D it would be easy but I never tried to make such a project in 3D (low poly texturized) and now I'm struggling with the terrain.
I don't know if this is the best or worse approach but so far I split my map up in different sections:

Issue now comes with texturing. Some parts are mountainous, beach, forest roads and paths.
I could create for every part a UV map, which from a performance perspective would certainly not be recommended.
Another method which comes to my mind would be a splat map, a color map, in which each color value represent a different texture. But I don't know how senseful that would be on a "big" map like this, never tried it, maybe it will end in a disaster.
Maybe I have to write an own terrain paint tool, but as far as I saw it comes with limitations like you can only use a limited amount of textures.
Maybe someone can give some good pointers on how to approach this?
